# In Excel using VBA code, is there a way to conditionally hide/unhide rows based on 1 cell, and then hide/unhide rows in a table based on another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, hide

This is my current code that works for the first part of my solution.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("D5") = "1 Term" Then
        Rows("15:166").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("167:625").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "2 Terms" Then
        Rows("15:167").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("168:319").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("320:625").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "3 Terms" Then
        Rows("15:320").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("321:472").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("473:625").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "4 Terms" Then
        Rows("15:473").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("474:625").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("D5") = "None" Then
        Rows("12:625").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
```

There are 4 tables that appear when each "Term" is selected. Once a "Term" is selected, I want to be able to put a number 1-150 in cell E5, and it will conditionally only show the number of rows (in three tables) that is listed.

[Here is a visual of my Excel sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qXtv.png)

I have tried just hiding full rows based on E5, but there is one table that I would like to stay visible, no matter what number is selected.

The following code worked with no issues! But again, there is one table that I want to be visible no matter what. If I put "2" in E5, then the table also disappears.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$5" Then
        If Target.Value = "1 Term" Then
            Rows("15:166").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("167:625").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("E10:E12").EntireRow.Hidden = False ' Unhide cells E10 to E12
        ElseIf Target.Value = "2 Terms" Then
            Rows("15:167").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("168:319").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("320:625").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("E10:E12").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' Hide cells E10 to E12
        ElseIf Target.Value = "3 Terms" Then
            Rows("15:320").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("321:472").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("473:625").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("E10:E12").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' Hide cells E10 to E12
        ElseIf Target.Value = "4 Terms" Then
            Rows("15:473").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("474:625").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("E10:E12").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' Hide cells E10 to E12
        ElseIf Target.Value = "None" Then
            Rows("12:625").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("E10:E12").EntireRow.Hidden = False ' Unhide cells E10 to E12
        End If
    End If
    
    If Target.Address = "$E$5" Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            If Target.Value >= 1 And Target.Value <= 150 Then
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 16 To 166
                    If i <= Target.Value + 15 And i >= 16 Then
                        Rows(i).Hidden = False
                    Else
                        Rows(i).Hidden = True
                    End If
                Next i
                If Range("D5") = "None" Then
                    Range("A12:A14").EntireRow.Hidden = False ' Unhide cells A12 to A14
                Else
                    Range("A12:A14").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' Hide cells A12 to A14
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI in `Rows(...).EntireRow` the `Entirerow` is redundant - `Rows()` is already the full row.

Comment: "there is one table that I would like to stay visible" - which table is that?

Comment: @TimWilliams The first table (grading scale) is the one that I want to stay visible.

Comment: Then don't you need to shift it up so it doesn't get hidden when hiding rows in the other tables?

Comment: @TimWilliams I was hoping there was a way to hide the row tables and not the actual rows. I don't want to shift up, because I like the uniformity of the tables.

Comment: Tables don't work that way - hiding a row means hiding the whole row for that sheet.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good start:

```
Sub MakeVisibleNoMatterWhat()

    Dim myRow As Range
    For Each myRow In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:F15").Rows
        Debug.Print myRow.Address
        myRow.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next myRow

End Sub
```

Just make sure that you are working on `Sheet1` or change the sheet name in the code. Then, later try to make the code better, assigning the range as a variable and passing it to the function.

Call the function at the end of your code:

```
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    MakeVisibleNoMatterWhat
End Sub
```